# AmCharts 4 "animateData is not a function" or 'How to reanimate chart new data'?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using AmCharts4 by including it in footer.

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script>am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);</script>
```

I am able to draw a chart and it animates on load, but would love to make it animate on receiving new data.
both `chart.animateAgain()` or `chart.animateData()` throws me `TypeError: chart.animateAgain is not a function`.

To create the chart I did `chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);`

To assign new data I just did `chart.data = newData`.

Comment: Well, there's no `animateAgain` or `animateData` in RadarChart's [methods](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/radarchart/#Methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animateData` and `animateAgain` are methods in version 3. Version 4 has a completely different API.

To redraw the chart and trigger the animation again in version 4, you can call `invalidateData`, which is also useful in cases where you need to [manually update the chart](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Manipulating_existing_data_points). You can also call `deepInvalidate` if you really want to trigger a full redraw, but it's very performance heavy and the documentation warns to only do this if [absolutely necessary](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#deepInvalidate_method).

Comment: Thanks, `invalidateRawData` works, but only if I specify the exact data item:
`chart.data[0].value = newValue`

Doesn't work for the whole set like `chart.data = newData`.
Any ideas how could do the whole set? 
My dataset looks like this:
`chart.data = [
          {category: "GHG", value: 15},
          {category: "DEF", value: 17}
]
`

Comment: `deepInvalidate` triggers a full redraw with animation, it's just a heavier method in comparison. `invalidateData` works with the whole set in my testing, sometimes it doesn't do a full redraw in random cases. Those are your only options, unfortunately.